# Plot a bezier triangle

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, splines

I have to construct a bezier triangle that interpolates these 4 points:

$\qquad (0,0,1),\,(1,0,0),\,(0,1,0),\,(0.5,0.5,0.75)$

However, the surface that I get is so weird. Anyone please can help me to solve this problem?

```
pts = 
  {{{0, 0, 1}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.75}, {1, 0, 0}}, 
   {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.75}}, 
   {{0, 1, 0}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.75}, {1, 0, 0}}};
f = BezierFunction[pts]

Show[
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], Red, Map[Point, pts]}],
  Graphics3D[{Gray, Line[pts], Line[Transpose[pts]]}],
  ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
    Mesh -> Full, 
    Axes -> True,
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: bezier triangle]

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to correct in your plot

Comment: Please add a new question in this forum instead of edit your old question! Your original problem is about Bezier Surface!

Comment: The usual definition of Bezier triangle is *not* equivalent to some degenerated Bezier quadrilateral patch. So it can't be represented by `BezierFunction` with some control points being "squeezed" together. For more details, please check my Community post [*A Gentle Introduction to Bézier Triangle*](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1884868).

Answer (score 4):

```
a = {1, 0, 0};
b = {0, 1, 0};
c = {0, 0, 1};
d = {0.5, 0.5, 0.75};
m = 1.38 d;
pts = {{a, a, a, a}, 
      {2/3 a + 1/3 b, m, m, 2/3 a + 1/3 c}, 
      {2/3 b + 1/3 a, m, m, 2/3 c + 1/3 a}, 
      {b, 2/3 b + 1/3 c, 2/3 c + 1/3 b, c}};
f = BezierFunction[pts];
Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.04], Point[{a, b, c, d}]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], Red, Map[Point, pts]}], 
 Graphics3D[{Gray, Line[pts], Line[Transpose[pts]]}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], Mesh -> Full, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ViewPoint -> {1.64, -0.14, 2.95}]
```

[image]

Comment: @cvgmat can we convert B-spline to  Bezier spline in mathematica?

Comment: The attempt to represent Bezier triangle with `BezierFunction` is not quite correct. Please see [my comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235541/plot-a-bezier-triangle#comment696184_235541) under OP.