# Plot a quadratic bezier triangular patch

Tags: plotting, splines

I need to construct a triangular patch by using the 6 control points:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
  \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4},1\right) & \left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4},2\right) &
  \left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4},2\right) \\
  (0,0,1) & \left(\frac{1}{2},0,2\right) & (1,0,1) \\
\end{array}$$

However, the surface seems not like a triangular patch. Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Here is the code:

```
pts = 
  {{{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 1}, {0, 0, 1}},
   {{1/4, Sqrt[3]/4, 2}, {1/2, 0, 2}},
   {{3/4, Sqrt[3]/4, 2}, {1, 0, 1}}};
f = BezierFunction[pts]

Show[
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], Red, Map[Point, pts]}], 
  Graphics3D[{Gray, Line[pts], Line[Transpose[pts]]}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"],
    Mesh -> Full,
    Axes -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: See: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235541/plot-a-bezier-triangle

Comment: There’s a mismatch for the first control point in the list and your code. The code is `Sqrt[3]/2`. Did you mean `Sqrt[3]/4` in both places?

Comment: When you include code in your questions, please check that you can copy from the question and paste into Mathematica without errors. It’s better for people who can help if they can easily copy and paste.